# How to backup my phpmyadmin correctly?

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin, database-backups, database-restore

I have a problem with my server. Then I try to backup all database in my phpmyadmin.First, after login I choose `DATABASE --> SELECT EXPORT --> THEN SELECT ALL DATABASE -> THEN DOING EXPORT`.
[image]

But, after i want to restore it into new phpmyadmin some database not restore.

`mysql -u root -p > localhost.sql`

why ?

---

EDIT

i make whole database inside phpmyadmin are backup.after restore only 3 databases which restored another 2 databases not show (this database have around 200.000 rows)

Answer (score 0):

It's won't work cause all Database inside PHPMYADMIN are downloaded as a single file. Such as Information schema and all phpmyadmin setting are backed up.

This trouble will be happen because during restore to new phpmyadmin the old information schema meet the default information schema from new one. After read from some sites, they said that don't replace it with the old one.

So, just some dump query which success to restore (this query before infomation schema dump query). But, for the next query ( after information schema dump query) can't restore. Then I must restore one by one DB inside that file.

Note :

Backup all database except information schema or other stuff outside your own DB
If your DB is too large, better use MySQL shell.

Answer (score 0):

If localhost.sql contains a full mysqldump, then you want to pipe it into mysql:

```
mysql -u root -p < localhost.sql
```

In your question, you are using output redirection (>), not input redirection (<)

I don't know if phpMyAdmin will create dump files that contain CREATE DATABASE commands or not.  It might have an option for that.  If you are still missing some databases, create them with CREATE DATABASE first.